# Google photos duplicates between original and High Quality

Tags: google-photos

I currently have all my photos uploaded in High Quality in Google Photos.  I initially used Picasa to organize them into albums from my folder structure.  After they stopped supporting Picasa, I would manually uploaded via the web interface.
I recently got a Pixel (which allows unlimited original), so I copied all my photos to my Pixel and had it upload all of the to Google Photos in Original quality.

I THOUGHT that Google Photos would be smart enough to detect duplicates and replace the High Quality with Original, but it did not, and now I basically have two copies of all of my photos with Originals all unlabeled.

Every "solution" I have found online is old, involving use of Picasa or Google Drive.

Is there any solution out there for my issue?  Perhaps something via the API?

The only other thing I can think of is to delete everything, re-upload, manually label which of course is not ideal.

Answer (score -2):

If you have photos or videos in a Picasa Web Album, the easiest way to still access, modify and share most of that content is to log in to Google Photos. Your photos and videos will already be there.